# How to pass parameter to Jenkins service

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins service which I run like `sudo service jenkins start|stop`. Now, I want to pass a parameter `--prefix=/jenkins` to this service. I tried `sudo service jenkins --prefix=/jenkins` but this param is ignored. How can I pass this additional param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit `/etc/default/jenkins`. The quick and dirty way is to find the variable `JENKINS_ARGS="..."` at the end of the file. Simply add `--prefix=/jenkins` there.

Let's say that you had:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT"
```

it should be:

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --prefix=/jenkins"
```

The nice way is to edit the variable `PREFIX` which should be located a few lines above, in my case it was `PREFIX=/$NAME`, change that to `PREFIX=/jenkins` and then, similar to before, you edit `JENKINS_ARGS` and add `--prefix=$PREFIX`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **extend your init script**. According to the `service` [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/service),

> service passes COMMAND and OPTIONS it to the init script unmodified

It depends on your distribution, but most likely your init script does *not* handle any additional options. If you fix that, then you will be able to pass parameters.

Having said this, the proper way to establish settings in a more permanent way is the one described by Jon S.